# Linq-to-XML: query cleanup

Tags: linq-to-xml

New to Linq, trying to query an XDocument.
I want elements where a certain attribute is equal to one of two values.

Looking for suggestions on how to streamline this query:

`query = from xElem in doc.Descendants(StringLiterals._streamNodeName)

                        where ((0 == xElem.Attribute(StringLiterals._typeAttributeName).Value.CompareTo(StringLiterals._sWorkspace)) ||

                               (0 == xElem.Attribute(StringLiterals._typeAttributeName).Value.CompareTo(StringLiterals._sNormal)))

select new AccuRevXmlElement

    {

    _location = xElem.Attribute(StringLiterals._nameAttributeName).Value,

_streamNumber = xElem.Attribute(StringLiterals._streamNumberAttributeName).Value

};`

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are quite well underway but you can streamline it a little (untested):

```
from xElem in doc.Descendants(StringLiterals._streamNodeName)
let typeAttributeValue = xElem.Attribute(StringLiterals._typeAttributeName).Value
where typeAttributeValue == StringLiterals._sW... ||
      typeAttributeValue == StringLiterals._sNormal
select new AccuRevXmlElement
{
    _location = xElem.Attribute(StringLiterals._nameAttributeName).Value,
    _streamNumber =
        xElem.Attribute(StringLiterals._streamNumberAttributeName).Value
};
```

The key differences are the `let` keyword that introduces a new variable inside the query and the fact that you can compare strings using the `==` operator since `System.String` implements this operator.

Comment: Much better, and I learned about the let keyword...
Does 'let' behave like 'var', where the variable gets its type from the rhs?
Thanks for the reply.